# Access VBA Save File Multiple Filter

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

I want to save a query in either xls or xlsx. I can get the drop down of 2 filters working but when i run an If statement to either save the document as acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 or 10 it does not see the strfilter as "Excel 97-2003 (.xls)" or "Excel 2007+ (.xlsx)" and always goes to the ELSE. Any help would be appreciated to get this working properly.
Any questions please let me know.
Cheers.

```
strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel 97-2003 (.xls)", "*.xls")
strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel 2007+ (.xlsx)", "*.xlsx")
strSaveFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                                OpenFile:=False, _
                                Filter:=strFilter, _
                Flags:=ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT Or ahtOFN_READONLY)
If strFilter = "Excel 97-2003 (.xls)" Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "xlsquery", strSaveFileName
Else
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "xlsxquery", strSaveFileName
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

`strFilter` does not get changed by the user's choice in the dialog box. However, you should be able to deduce the choice made from looking at the end of `strSaveFileName`.

```
If Right(strSaveFileName, 4)= ".xls" Then
     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "xlsquery", strSaveFileName
ElseIf Right(strSaveFileName, 5)= ".xlsx" Then
     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "xlsxquery", strSaveFileName
Else
    'handle bad file extention here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm prety sure the filter is "*.xls", not "Excel 97-2003 (.xls)".  If you put a code break in on your IF line, you can hover your mouse over strFilter and see exactly what Access thinks that variable is equal to.

Comment: It is giving me this: Excel 97-2003 (.xls) *.xls Excel 2007+ (.xlsx) *.xlsx
It seems to be pulling through both filters but I just need the filter I have selected? Thanks.